# return codes for net registry enumerate ? while trying to access samba's registry from linux

Tags: registry, samba, enumerate

I'm trying to read the value of a samba's registry using the command

```
net registry enumerate 'Path\To\The\Value'
$?
-bash: 255: command not found
```

and the command is returning a 255, i executed the command with another keys and returns the information and the return code is 0 as expected

I'm trying to find what this 255 means
does anybody knows where can i find something like an api?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape backslashes when you use them on the command-line in most shells, like so:

```
net registry enumerate 'Path\\To\\The\\Value'
```